# Delete document on the basis of id match in the array field. in laravel

Tags: php, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

i am working on api in laravel for delete chats document in the firebase
following is my code

```
  $collectionRef = $db->collection('chats');
    $query = $collectionRef->where('participantId', 'array-contains', $userId);

    $querySnapshot = $query->documents();

    foreach ($querySnapshot as $document) {
        Log::info("QuerySnapshot data: " . print_r($document->data(), true));
        $document->reference()->delete();
        Log::info("Chat document deleted: " . $document->id());
    }

    $docRef = $db->collection('users')->document($userId);
    $docRef->delete();
```

**i need to delete the chats document where participantId's match with my requested id but it is not working where i am wrong?**

here is my firestore collection screenshot.
[image: in image there is collection "chats" inside the document there is field "participantId"]

Comment: "is not working" doesn't provide enough information so we can help. Have you tried to see if something goes wrong when you actually delete the document? Do you have the proper rules?

Comment: Entire document is not deleting for above code. but the fields inside the documents are deleted on calling this api.

Comment: So you end up with an empty document?

Comment: What is the type of your `$userId` variable? In the database the `participantId` array contains numbers, so it's important that you pass a number to the query too.

Answer (score 0):

When your document contains a sub-collection, such as `chats/10295/Messages`, when you delete the document `chats/10295` then the sub-collection(s) are not deleted. These deleted documents will continue to appear in the Firebase console so that you can browse to the sub-collections.

If you want to delete the `chats/{id}` document and all sub-collections, then you will need to update your code to recursively delete the `Messages` sub-collection. I'm not a PHP developer, but [these code snippets will guide you for deleting the sub-collection](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/delete-data#python_2).